# Manipulate strings to prepend a character and remove characters

Tags: excel, vba, string

I have a spreadsheet that has a column of tens of thousands of stock identifiers in the format: 2.269-345.0.

I need to put a "K" as the first character, remove all "." and "-" from the stock id and also remove the last character "0".

Comment: Can you edit your question, showing your macro?

Comment: Always remove the last character or only when it is 0 ?

Comment: This is best resolved with Power Query. Have you tried using it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Function stripString(ByVal str2strip As String) As String
      Dim tmpStr As String: tmpStr = ""
      If str2strip = "" Then GoTo stripString_Exit
      tmpStr = "K" & str2strip
      tmpStr = Replace(tmpStr, ".", "")
      tmpStr = Replace(tmpStr, "-", "")
      tmpStr = IIf(Right(tmpStr, 1) = 0, Left(tmpStr, Len(tmpStr) - 1), tmpStr)
      stripString = tmpStr
stripString_Exit:
      Exit Function
stripString_Err:
End Function
```

Comment: Maybe nitpicking, but you should use `Right(tmpStr, 1) = "0"` - you compare against the character "0", not the number 0.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just using functions:

```
"K"&LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",),"-",),7)
```

[image]

Then drag down and copy paste.special values...

Comment: ... and what if the last character is not a zero?

Comment: @Dominique does OP state "remove the last character ONLY IF it is a 0" ? If that is true then an if() can sort that. But it is possible that the last character should be removed...

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways.

```
'Can use as a worksheet formula.
Public Function MyFormula(Target As Range) As String
    MyFormula = "K" & Replace(Replace(Target, ".", ""), "-", "")
End Function  

'Or can cycle through each cell and replace the value.
Public Sub ReplaceAll()

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A3")
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In MyRange
        Cell = MyFormula(Cell)
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Or you could replace the `MyFormula` function with:

```
Public Function MyFormula(Target As Range) As Long
    MyFormula = Replace(Replace(Target, ".", ""), "-", "") * 1
End Function
```

and then create a custom number format of `"K"#`.  This will turn the text into a number - the cell will contain just the number so you can use it in formula, but will be displayed with a preceding "K".
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in a regular module.
Select the desired range, then ALT + F8, and choose "fnFormatting" to run.

```
Option Explicit

Sub fnFormatting()
    Dim oCell As Excel.Range
    Dim intX As Integer
    Dim strChar As String * 1
    Dim strText As String
    '>>>>> First, select the range to be used here, then ALT + F8, then run the macro <<<<<
    
    For Each oCell In Selection
        For intX = 1 To Len(oCell)
            strChar = Mid(oCell, intX, 1)
                If strChar Like "[0-9]" Then strText = strText & IIf(intX = Len(oCell) And strChar = "0", "", strChar)
        Next
        oCell.Value = "K" & strText
        strText = ""
    Next
End Sub
```